# Prevent new tab when opening URL from C#

Tags: c#

I have a C# application that opens a URL in the default browser when the user double clicks on the System Tray icon provided by the app.

1. How can I prevent a new tab opening when the user double clicks again, after already opening the browser at that URL?
2. Is it possible to set the focus to that already opened tab instead?

I am using `Process.Start(url);` to open the browser

Comment: Couldn't you just embed a browser window in your app to achieve this?  Is there any reason you're launching the external browser?

Comment: I'm actually in the middle of updating the app to no longer have a desktop UI, all that will be visually present is the icon in the system tray

Comment: You could try scanning existing windows to determine if your web application is active. However, there is no quick and easy way to do this. If I were you, I would rethink this idea. Why prevent the user from opening two windows of a web application?